# Fetch data from size table by getting id from mapping table in django?

Tags: python, django, database

I am creating a printing ordering service website in django and i am stuck on order page.
I have three tables named "product" ,"size" and "sizeProductMap" table.

***model.py***

This is my product table.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image",upload_to='productImage/', null=True)
```

This is the size table.

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size_id = models.AutoField("Size ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    prod_size = models.CharField("Product Size", max_length=20, null=False)
```

This is the sizeProductMapping table.

```
class SizeProductMapping(models.Model):
    size_p_map_id = models.AutoField("Size & Product Map ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    size_id = models.ForeignKey(Size, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Size ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product Id")
```

The sizeProductMap tables stores primary key of product table and size table as foreign key, now i want to get those sizes which has mapping with a particular product.

I want to get all those sizes from size table releted to a particular product here a single product can have different sizes.

Comment: Can you paste your model.py code showing how the relationships were setup?

Comment: i have added the models now can you help me ? I am a newbie at project development so needed help i don't know how to fetch the all the sizes releted to a product . Suggest he cde i should try in views.py  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code, there are many sizes are available for a single products so when i visit the product page i want all the sizes listed their so i can choose one of them, In example think i have a product "Envelop" it may have different sizes so i need all those options.
so i tried something lit me share with you:

**views.py**

```
    def product(request, id):
        ''' using id I am getting the product here'''

        products = Product.objects.get(prod_ID=id)
        print(products)

        '''According to foreign key relationship here I am getting all the mappings available to that product'''

        sizesmap = SizeProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
        for data in sizesmap:
            ''' Here storing all the sizes id in "sizes" variable'''
            sizes = data.size_id
            
        '''Here I am getting all the sizes related to that product and printing it now I can pass it in context and use it in the page'''
            print(sizes.prod_size)
        return HttpResponse(sizesmap)
```

Comment: Yes, this thing is working for me correctly. I thank you for giving your precious reply to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you can modify with your models and database.  If you are using an existing database with data you don't want to lose, then there are things you can do.  But I'm not listing them here.

The Django way of doing what you want is to use one of the built-in relationship constructs Django provides. There are two that could fit your needs. Either a One-To-Many or a Many-To-Many.  I'll provide examples of both.

Depending on the possible values for size, you may just want a One-to-Many:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image",upload_to='productImage/', null=True)

class Size(models.Model):
    size_id = models.AutoField("Size ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    prod_size = models.CharField("Product Size", max_length=20, null=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

This will create a One-To-Many relationship with Product and size.  Then to get all of the sizes for a given product:

```
p = Product.object.get(prod_id=<whatever>)
for size in p.size_set.all():
   print('{} - {}'.format(p.productName, size.prod_size))
```

Here is an interactive shell example of getting multiple sizes for a single product.

```
>>> p = Product.objects.create(prod_Name='test', prod_Desc='test2')
>>> p.size_set.create(prod_size='Medium')
<Size: Size object (1)>
>>> p.size_set.create(prod_size='Large')
<Size: Size object (2)>
>>> for size in p.size_set.all():
...    print(size.prod_size)
... 
Medium
Large
```

Your example uses a ManyToMany relationship, which [Django can create and manage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) that middle table for you as well.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image",upload_to='productImage/', null=True)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField("Size2")

class Size(models.Model):
    size_id = models.AutoField("Size ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    prod_size = models.CharField("Product Size", max_length=20, null=False)
```

Then to query it

```py
for sizes in product.sizes.all():
   print(product.prod_Name, sizes.prod_size)
```

Some interactive shell done with the ManyToMany example:

```
>>> p = Product.objects.create(prod_Name='foo', prod_Desc='bar')
>>> p.sizes.create(prod_size='medium')
<Size: Size object (1)>
>>> p.sizes.create(prod_size='small')
<Size: Size object (2)>
>>> for s in p.sizes.all():
...    print(s)
... 
Size object (1)
Size object (2)
>>> for s in p.sizes.all():
...    print(s.prod_size)
... 
medium
small
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply,  but it didn't worked for me cause there are different sizes available for a single products so whenever i click on a product i want all the sizes which are related to that product so the mapping table is necessary .

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work.  But both examples with the ManyToMany and the OneToMany  provide you with different sizes available for a single product from a database.  I'll edit with some code to populate the database.